# Merge tags "dropdown", "drop-down", "drop-down-menu", "css-dropdown"

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I would like these tags to be merged under "dropdown", most common tag used by SO-pedians. This is how it now stands.
[dropdown](/questions/tagged/dropdown) (4671 questions).
[drop-down](/questions/tagged/drop-down) (67 questions).
[drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) (501 questions).
[css-dropdown](/questions/tagged/css-dropdown) (7 questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is done.  The following tags were merged into a new tag [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) (which took the wiki from [dropdown](/questions/tagged/dropdown)):

- [dropdown](/questions/tagged/dropdown)
- [drop-down](/questions/tagged/drop-down)
- [dropdown-menu](/questions/tagged/dropdown-menu)

I did *not* merge these into [css-dropdown](/questions/tagged/css-dropdown) (which [doesn't exist as of this writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-dropdown)) as it just doesn't make sense.  Drop-down menus are *not* specific to CSS, and this suggests either a specific tag ([css-drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/css-drop-down-menu)) or a combination of the [css](/questions/tagged/css) *and* [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) tags.

I've opted for the latter.  Of the seven, I made sure that those questions were tagged [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu).

However there [*one* question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9161359/50776) that was about the [WordPress CSS Drop-down Menu plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-css-drop-down-menu/), and for that question, I created the [wp-css-drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/wp-css-drop-down-menu) tag, as it refers to a *very* specific plugin.  I've also created a rudimentary tag wiki for it to help disambiguate it from other questions involving WordPress, CSS and/or drop down menus.

Comment: The new tag you created might be too specific. I hope that isn't the only question with that tag in the long run.

Comment: @nhahtdh In retrospect, it is, I've deleted the tag and retagged it appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

This seems reasonable except that not all are for html dropdown menus. Thus I would suggest the first 3 are merged but [css-dropdown](/questions/tagged/css-dropdown) is left separate

Comment: I think "css-dropdown" should be included because. There are only 7 questions in "css-dropdown". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropdown-menu+css has 216 questons. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropdown+css has 462 questons. Those tags are preferred by SO-pedians for css-dropdown-menues.

Comment: @OlofAdler I disagree with you.  First, CSS drop down menus are a specialization of drop down menus.  They should either be tagged with `css-drop-down-menu` or `css` and `drop-down-menu`.  All the others should be a singular `drop-down-menu` tag.  Simply put, just because the current number of questions on Stack Overflow *favor* a technology is not proof that the tag is *exclusive* to that technology.  Drop down menus are not specific to CSS (by *any* means) so it's better to not to merge into that.

Comment: So. Either a merge into a single [dropdown] or [drop-down-menu]. We could leave [css-dropdown] but for that to be accurate. Almost 700 questions have to be re-tagged!, (who is going to do that?). I personally don't like 7-questions-tags and would rather see [dropdown]+[css] as a selective criteria. That's just me, I'm not rigid on this.

Comment: @OlofAdler See my answer.  Also, you realize [there is no `css-dropdown` tag, right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-dropdown)?  I don't know what you're referring to there.  However, I've done most of what you've suggested, as well as addressed those seven specific questions.